# Coin toss how fair is the coin?

Tags: probability

A coin, which you are not allowed to examine, is either a fair coin (P(heads) = 1/2) or has two heads. Your initial opinion is P(fair) = 0.9. The coin is flipped and heads comes up. What is your opinion now? The coin is flipped a second time and again heads comes up. What is your opinion now?

For the first question, I am thinking:

P(fair/heads on the 1st toss)=$(1/2)*0.9/((1/2)*0.9+1*0.1) = 0.45/0.55$

For the second question:

P(fair/heads on the 2nd toss again)=$(1/4)*0.9/((1/4)*0.9+1*0.1)$ ?

Am I on the right track with this question?

Comment: I feel like this is not a well-defined question. What do you mean by "opinion" here? The closest thing I could think of is conditional or something Bayesian...

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct.

Comment: @Misakov, I guess that opinion here is the same as believe...in some ocassions the probability that we assign to an event is based on beliefs...

Comment: @CarlosMendoza I totally get what you mean. That's exactly why I always feel frustrated when probability questions come up as interview questions...

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As André stated in a comment, your analysis is correct. A more usual term in this context for what you call "opinion" would be "belief".